# Converting hose size from CO2 tank

Tags: kegging, co2

So I am almost done fermenting my first batch of home brew and am about to start kegging it.  The only problem is the current hose coming from the regulator is a good bit wider than the nozzle I have on my homebrew keg.  Is this something that can be fixed somehow, or should I look to replace one of the nozzels?  Does the hose width matter much for delivering the pressure to the keg?

EDIT: connector looks like this:

[image]

EDIT: looking back on this question, I notice this picture shows a barb that could be screwed off, mine at the time was not like that, had a particular barb all connected as one piece.

Comment: what kind of keg connection are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally got it all fixed up.  What I ended up using was just replacing the piece connected to the homebrew keg with a different piece I got at a local homebrew shop for a few bucks.

[image]

Basically this allowed me to screw on the size of barbed connector I needed.

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing 100% what is available near you (saw that you are from the states which seems like a place where you can get almost anything from your local shop) there are hose-adapaters that you can buy, these are how they look in Sweden; [Slangadapter](http://biltema.se/sv/Bat/VVS/Nipplar--Bordgenomforing/Slangadapter-25989/).

**EDIT:**
After doing a bit of digging I found that they are typcally called 'Union Reducers' and can be found online; [Union Reducer](http://www.grainger.com/product/PARKER-Union-Reducer-2GUF7?s_pp=false)

The width of the hose won't matter too much. Since you are delivering low pressures (1-2 bar) the thickness will not affect the possibility to deliver pressure.

Comment: I don't see how this will work, unless you also use another piece of smaller hose to connect the reducer to the quick disconnect on the keg.

Comment: Yes, you would. But since the question was asked to find a solution OR switch the nozzles, this would be one of the other solutions...

Answer (score 2):

It's common to use 1/4" quick disconnect barbs and flange connectors (as shown in your photo) with a 5/8" gas hose. Just be sure to use either a worm clamp or oeteker clamp on the hose to keep it in place on the barb.

Alternatively, you can get 5/8" barbs for the flange connector, but I'm not sure it's necessary.

Comment: Hmm, OK I'll give it a try.  If not I can probably find the part Sander mentioned at a hardware store, I'll see which seems to make the most sense.  Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Perfect that you resolve it!
Sorry there is no Slangadapter in Biltema.

Regards
Björn

[tiling.se](https://tiling.se/plattsattningsverktyg/verktyg)